# Escaping from assembly land when debugging Objective-C in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

When debugging Objective-C code in Xcode I am often thrown into assembly land.

Ideally I would never want to step into assembly. I have disabled the option

```
Debug > Debug Workflow > Always show Disassembly
```

I also use `step over` as my default stepping method instead of `step into`.

But still, quite often I enter into assembly land and have to press `step out` many times before I am finally back in my code.

As you can see I am already thinking about two things. I have not found any setting like `just debug my code`.

Do you have any advice for how I can lower (ideally to zero) the time I spend in assembly code

Comment: Not sure you can do much about it.  There is code in your program that you don't have the source code for and there is no other way of telling you where you are in the callstack/codebase.

Comment: It would be nice to have some option to always step over until non-assembly code or throw an error if an error happens somewhere before that